# JpaRepository: using repositories in @PostPersist

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, h2

I have two entities

```
class A {
    ...
    Integer totalSum;
    Set<B> b;
}

class B {
    ...
    Integer value;
    A container;
}
```

I want a.totalSum to be sum of each a.b.value;

Maybe best solution is view in db, but I want listen changes in BRepository and update A-records.

I do:

```
@PostPersist
@PostUpdate
@PostRemove
private void recalculateSums(B b) {
    AutowireHelper.autowire(this, this.aRepository);
    AutowireHelper.autowire(this, this.bRepository);
    A a =   b.getContainer();
    a.setTotalSum(bRepository.sumByA(s));
    aRepository.save(s);
}
```

And in BRepository:

```
@Query("select sum(b.value) from B b where b.container = :a")
Long sumByA(@Param("a") A a);
```

And I have error: `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.B(ID)"; SQL statement:
insert into b (VALUE, CONTAINER_ID, ID) values (?, ?, ?)`

**What I'm doing wrong?**

If I do

```
    a.setTotalSum(a.getTotalSum()+1);
    aRepository.save(s);
```

All works, but if I do

```
    a.setTotalSum(a.getTotalSum()+1);
    aRepository.saveAndFlush(s);
```

I have the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I can see why you might want to do this but I think it creates a whole load of potential issues around data integrity.

If you want to have the sum of B available for an A without having to load and iterate all B there are three other options which you could implement all of which would be more robust than your proposal.

1. As you noted, create a view. You can then Map an Entity say, SummaryData, to this view and map a one-to-one from A to SummaryData so that you can do a.getSummaryData().getTotalSum();
2. Alternatively, you could use the Hibernate specific @Formula annotation which will issue an inline select when the entity is loaded.

   @Formula("(select sum(value) from B b inner join A a where b.a_id= a.id and a.id =id
   private int totalSum;
3. Finally, and depending on the capabilities of your database, you could create a Virtual Column and Map a property as you would for any other field.

1 and 3 obviously require schema changes but your app would remain JPA compliant. 2 does not require any schema change but breaks strict JPA compliance if that was important.

Comment: Thank You. `@Formula` helps me. But I still don't understand how to do it with my method properly.

Comment: `@Formula` has one serious lack for me - I want make index by this column. And I couldn't do it with `@Formula`. I can do It with trigger on db, but I if I want create independent of db app I think it better do with hibernate interceptor..